# cordova jqm fixed header moves after soft keyboard close

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have faced an issue on cordova android app, the jquery mobile fixed header will move after user opens and closes soft keyboard.

[image: Normal] [image]

The first diagram shown the normal fixed header at its correct position. User will press + button and enter some value by using soft keyboard. After user finishes the action, soft keyboard will disappear. **It will not happen every time, but sometimes the fixed header will be moved after the soft keyboard is closed, as shown in second diagram.**


Even through visually the content is moved, but in fact they still stay in their original position e.g. if I want to press menu button(left of header), instead of its position shows in screen, I need to press on empty space, which is its original position, then I only can trigger the event. 


I tried to search for solution in google. The conclusion is it looks like a bug in jquery mobile, but so far I did not have any solution. Please help me if you have correct solution, thank you

```
  <div data-role="page" id="">  
        <!-- main div container -->
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- row div -->
            <div class="row">
                <!-- top menu div -->
                <div class="row-xs-4">
                    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
                        <a class= 'btn'><span class="fui-home" style='font-size:15px;'></span></a>
                        <h1>Result</h1>
                        <a class="btn btn-primary"><span class="fui-gear" style='font-size:15px;'></span></a>
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- end top menu div -->
                <!-- content div -->
                <div class="row-xs-4">
                <!-- @@BODY CONTENT HERE@@ --> 
                </div> <!-- end content div --> 
            </div> <!-- end div container -->
        </div>
    </div>
```